# How to make files from app save in specified directory?

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-compose

I have a docker image that is basically Apache Tomcat with my own application war extracted in it.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    image: app:1.33
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./data/uploads/documents:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/uploads/documents"
      - "./data/conf/application-prod.yml:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/config/application-prod.yml"
    environment:
      - "TZ=Europe/Belgrade"
    ports:
      - "8282:8080"
```

The issue is, even though my bound folder shows up in the container if I try to save files in my app that are supposed to go in "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/uploads/documents", they are saved in "/usr/local/tomcat" for some reason and I cannot access them via app since they aren't on the specified path, nor are they in the bound folder on my host machine.

I thought it was a permission issue, so I created "./data/uploads/documents" as a local user, and I also let Docker create it as root after a few tries, but nothing seemed to work.

Any helpful tips on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Not the solution to your problem, but I find it weird that you name your volumes like real paths. A volume should be a logical name that refers to a real/physical path. So instead of using `./data/uploads/documents` as a volume name, I would use something meaningful like `uploads` or whatever. Should look like `volumes: (new line) - uploads:/usr/localtomcat/webapps/app/uploads/documents`. This would perhaps help clear the confusion of you thinking the files should be written into ./data/uploads/documents. I do not see they being referenced in the yml, except as a volume name - merely a name.

Comment: Also, check the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/). Why do you define your volumes wrapped inside double quotes ? The docs sample does not include them, nor do my volumes in my docker compose files.

Comment: @Veverke I found it in the official documentation.
Basically:
- "real path on host machine:virtual path in docker container"

Comment: Can you share the link ? interesting.

Comment: Share us how your java app is building the absolute path : `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/uploads/documents`. If your app stores the file on some path but you expects into another folder, I think is something in your app, not related to docker

Comment: You are right. Quoting the docs: *The short syntax uses the generic [SOURCE:]TARGET[:MODE] format, where SOURCE can be **either a host path or volume name**. TARGET is the container path where the volume is mounted. Standard modes are ro for read-only and rw for read-write (default).*